# Adding a specification concerning two daughters, one with special status, in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to produce the following figure with `forest`:

[image: Tesniereian Stemma]

So what I am looking for is a style specification that says that daughter 1 (frapp) and daughter 2 (ant) together relate to A. Daughter 2 (ant) is more important, which is marked in the figure by the downward line bending to the right below `ant`.

Is there a way to integrate it into the example below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}


\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[un exemple
  [A
    [frapp]
     [ant] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

It is two relations involving three elements: A is the mother of frapp and ant. And ant is the head (most important element) inside of A. Is there a nice way to do this with `forest` styles?

**Edit:**

I followed the suggestion and experimented a bit with `edge path`. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
dg translation/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
(!u.parent anchor)-- +(0,-l)
(!p.north west)--(.north east)\forestoption{edge label};}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[un example
  [A
    [frapp, no edge]
     [ant, dg translation] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

A straight line of length `l` south and a line that covers the two daughters. I would then have to raise the line so that it is at the level of A again (and add some curviness). But I do not know how I get the distance. It is not `l` but a bit less. Alternatively I could draw from below of A but I do not know how far to the left and to the right to go, since this depends on the size of the daughters.

I also had to specify `no edge` on the other daughter. If this could somehow be avoided, this would be great.

**Edit 2:**

OK, following a comment of cfr, I got rid of the `no edge` specification in the tree:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\forestset{
dg translation/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
(!u.parent anchor)-- +(0,-l)
(!p.north west)--(.north east)\forestoption{edge label};},!p.edge'={}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[un example
  [A
    [frapp]
     [ant, dg translation] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

But I still do not know how I should draw the curvy line below A. The comment does not help me here.

**Edit 3:**

OK. I got this far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\forestset{
dg translation/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}, rounded corners=3pt]
% the line downwards
(!u.parent anchor)-- +($(0,-l)-(0,12pt)$)-- +($(12pt,-l)-(0,12pt)$)
% the horizontal line
($(!p.north west)+(0,l)-(0,14pt)$)--($(.north east)+(0,l)-(0,14pt)$)\forestoption{edge label};},!p.edge'={}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[un exemple
  [A
    [frapp]
     [ant, dg translation] ] ]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

This produces the following picture:

[image]

There are several things I am unhappy with: The code contains a manual shift upwards by 14pt. This does not work with other fontsizes.

Another question is how I get the horizontal line curvy. I found some ways to influence the line in `tikz`, but these are options to the path and it seems not possible to have two different edge paths in `forest`. So if I specify options like `rounded corners` it affects all the parts of the path, but I want to have two separate paths. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just change the `edge path`. See the manual.

Comment: I would draw the horizontal bit separately, after the nodes are typeset but before packing. I would attach this to the parent node as part of `dg translation` applied to the child i.e. specify it for the child, but do the drawing for the parent. I think you'd still need `no edge`, though.

Comment: Though you could obviously apply `no edge` automatically as part of the specification of `dg translation` by just telling it to apply the `no edge` part to the node's sibling rather than the node itself.

Comment: Curious. I didn't know you could do it that way - neater than my suggestion. For the curvy line, I would try just using the `tikz` key, maybe in `before packing` as part of the `dg translation` style.

Comment: Hm. I do not know what this means. The line should be right below the mother node but should have the extension of the daughters. I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Draw it however you prefer using regular TikZ code. The suggestion is just about how to automate it.

Comment: An `edge path` doesn't have to be straight. You can include bends and curves and arcs and whatever you like. I don't see any particular reason to draw it as part of the `edge path`, but there's no reason it needs to be straight if you do so. (If you don't do this and use `before packing` and `tikz`, you can refer to nodes with the assurance that they will exist. If you are careful, you can do this anyway. E.g. `(!u.parent anchor |- .west)` to refer to the point vertically aligned with the west of the current node and horizontally aligned with the parent anchor of its parent.)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** My original answer works only with **forest** version 1. Not only is the code below simpler, but it works equally well with both version 1 and version 2.

---

This was my solution. Note that Stefan Müller's solution for setting `no edge` on the sibling was much neater than my explicit use of `node walk` in the original version of this code, although the updated version below is simpler still.

I use the `tikz` key to draw the curvy horizontal line, rather than trying to put this into the `edge` path. This makes it easy to be sure the nodes I reference exist, although this could be incorporated into the drawing of the `edge` with a little care.

'VIN' is, of course, nodes' equivalent of people's 'VIP'.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
  },
  vin/.style={
    child anchor=south west,
    edge path={
      \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.parent anchor) -- (!u.parent anchor |- .west) [out=-90, in=180] to (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    for parent={
      before packing={
        tikz={
          \draw (!1.north west |- .parent anchor) [out=30, in=170] to (.parent anchor) [out=-10, in=-150] to (!l.north east |- .parent anchor);
        },
      },
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
     !p.no edge,
    },
  }
  [un exemple
    [A
      [frapp
      ]
      [ant, vin
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: bendy paths]

Comment: wow -- i think you read a different book of forest documentation -- how do i learn more about custom edge path definition -- do advise -- thanks